# Getting results of a ADOQuery to a Combobox

Tags: delphi

I have a database and would like to fill up a combobox with partnumbers where TYPE = RKE
But When i run this code it gives errors

Parameter xxx has no default value.

```
    procedure TFMain.ComboTypeClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Qry:TADOQuery;
begin
    Qry:=TADOQuery.Create(self);
  try
    Qry.Connection:=PronetConnection;  //pronet is adoconnection
    Qry.SQL.Clear;
    Qry.SQL.Add('Select PartNumber FROM PNet WHERE Type = RKE');
    Qry.Open;
    with Qry do
    begin
      First;
      ComboType.Items.Clear;
      while not eof do
      begin
        ComboNumber.Items.Add(FieldByName('PartNumber').AsString);
        Next;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Qry.Active:=False;
    Qry.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It is literally "parameter xxx" the message? at wich line of code do you get the error?

Comment: If the field `Type` is a string you must quote the RKE value.

Comment: Also notice you'll add the obtained records to ComboNumber items, but it looks like you want to add it to the ComboType items.

Comment: type was a string adding " " around the RKE worked .. make answer and ill approve :D  .. parameter [xxx]    where xxx was RKE or what ever i made it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is in the sql script.

```
Qry.SQL.Add('Select PartNumber FROM PNet WHERE Type = '+QuotedStr('RKE'));
```